# Guice FactoryBuilderModule NullPointerException On Generated Factory

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, factory

I am new to Guice and have done a lot of reading on this but I have not hand any success with this.  I am basically creating a DAO and want to use Guice and the AssistedInjection.  Effectively the end goal is create the Injected factory in other classes throughout the application.

Intended use in a actual class that would have the injection of the factory to then get classes from it

```
public class TestAllModelBootstrap {
   @Inject private DAOFactory factory;
   public TestAllModelBootstrap() {
   }

   @Test
   public void testGettingDAO() {
      Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new HibernateDAOModule());
      Token oToken = new OperTokenV1();
      AccountingDAO accountingDAO = factory.create(oToken);
   }
}
```

This is based on Guice-based code of:

```
public interface DAOFactory {
    public AccountingDAO create(Token oTicket);
}
```

The concrete class has a constructor annoated

```
@Inject
public HibernateAccountingDAO(@Assisted Token oTicket) {

    this.oTicket = oTicket;
}
```

And the actual Module:

```
@Override
protected void configure() {
    install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
            .implement(AccountingDAO.class, HibernateAccountingDAO.class)
            .build(DAOFactory.class));

    bind(SessionFactoryInterface.class)
            .toProvider(HibernateSessionProvider.class);
}
```

Each time I try to run this:
java.lang.NullPointerException -> indicating that the:

factory.create(oToken);

has factory as a null.  In reading up on the problem I was lead to believe that the injection will not work like I am using it in the "test" class.  It needs to be put in an "injected" class itself.  But this doesn't work either - if I wrapper the Factory injection in another class and then try to use it, it doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TestAllModelBootstrap` did not come from an Injector—JUnit created it instead—so Guice hasn't had a chance to inject it yet. Guice can only inject into objects that it creates via `getInstance` (and those objects' dependencies, recursively), or objects passed into [`injectMembers`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/Injector.html#injectMembers%28java.lang.Object%29), or existing instances as requested using [`requestInjection`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/Binder.html#requestInjection%28java.lang.Object%29).

You can manually get a factory instance:

```
factory = injector.getInstance(DAOFactory.class);
```

Or ask Guice to inject your members using [`injectMembers`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/Injector.html#injectMembers%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
injector.injectMembers(this); // sets the @Inject factory field
```

Or use a tool like [Guiceberry](https://code.google.com/p/guiceberry/) to inject your test cases across your app.

Comment: Thanks very much - in all my searching there was nothing that tied the ways to "inject" to the problem.  This is clear and using the factory = injector.getInstance(...) makes for a good way to get the factory without having to make class that uses the factory Guice injected.